# how to treat 2 different unicode characters as the same with php and mysql

Tags: mysql, unicode

I wanted to run a query that searches for a specific VARCHAR item in mysql DB. Since my project is Multi-lingual i have no choice but to use Unicode UTF8 as my charaset for that field.

The issue that i have is as follows:

> This Char ی and this Char ى looks the same
>
> However the unicode for above 2 is different (U+0649 & U+06CC)

I have alot of data and they contain mix of both above mentioned chars and many more.

There are many other characters in a similar way and what i need is a way to treat a series of these characters as the same so mysql matches them when i run the query.

I know it can be done by using OR in my query and including both the chars but is there any other way like maybe making my own charset/collation where i can define the two as same or if they look the same then they are treated the same?

Comment: Are you aware that these characters are different in usage and context?

Comment: Yes i am, but in my application that doesn't matter, as the data has been typed in using different keyboard models but ultimately with the same purpose.

Comment: In case of you only want to replace a small number of differenz letters, you could write an prcedure (e.g. as trigger) that is doing the replacement

Comment: ok, i didnt know about procedures in mysql, im gonna look into it.

Comment: But doing it as an update/insert trigger it will change the data provided by the user and you could also do it with your application one layer above. But you could do it also on selecting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want these to be treated as equal?

```
D989       1609=x0649  [ى]   AL  ARABIC LETTER ALEF MAKSURA
DB8C       1740=x06CC  [ی]   AL  ARABIC LETTER FARSI YEH
```

I checked `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`; they compare unequal:

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT(UNHEX('D989') USING utf8) =
    ->        CONVERT(UNHEX('DB8C') USING utf8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS x;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
```

I don't think MySQL will compare them as equal unless you create a custom collation.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-collation.html .

You could do set of REPLACE()s to change ى to ی before doing the comparison.  But that would be messy and slow.

Comment: i agree custom collation, seems right enough, thanks alot.